# Best way to select/highlight text (in text input) in Vue (using computed properties for value and selection range)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently we have an text input whose value is stored in our vuex store, passed in as props and retrieved via [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties). In that same vuex store we have a selection range (array of two numbers), which will allow text in the input to be selected/highlighted.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="value" @select="selectionHandler" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['props'],
    computed: {
      value: function() {
        return this.props.value // some string
      },
      selectionRange: {
        get: function () { return this.props.selectionRange }, // [number, number] 
        set: function (range) { /* dispatch store action to update, which will update props */ }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      selectionHandler(e) { 
        this.selectionRange = [e.currentTarget.selectionStart, e.currentTarget.selectionEnd]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The goal is to select/highlight the text (from the store) and update the store based on what the user selects. I'm planning to utilize `setSelectionRange` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)). I'm thinking I could use [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs) and [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), but that just seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a `select` function and using refs to select the input/textarea text. Initially I called `select` using Vue [life cycle methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram): [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) and [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated). So the simplified version looked like this:

```
<template>
  <input ref="someRefName" type="text" v-model="value" @select="selectionHandler" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['props'],
    computed: {
      value: function() {
        return this.props.value // some string
      },
      selectionRange: {
        get: function () { return this.props.selectionRange }, // [number, number] 
        set: function (range) { /* dispatch store action to update, which will update props */ }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      selectionHandler(e) { 
        this.selectionRange = [e.currentTarget.selectionStart, e.currentTarget.selectionEnd]
      },
      select() {
        this.$refs['someRefName'].setSelectionRange(this.selectionRange[0], this.selectionRange[1])
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
      if (this.selectionRange[1] !== 0) { this.select() }
    },
    updated: function () {
      if (this.selectionRange[1] !== 0) { this.select() }
    }
  }
</script>
```

That seemed like a pretty good solution... until I realized "*oh, that's not how browsers work.*" The selected/highlighted text gets cleared every time the input loses focus. So I changed it to use focus and blur handler functions. Now the text is only selected when the element is in focus. Something like this:

```
<template>
  <input ref="someRefName" type="text" v-model="value" @focus="focusHandler" @select="selectionHandler" @blur="blurHandler" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['props'],
    computed: {
      value: function() {
        return this.props.value // some string
      },
      selectionRange: {
        get: function () { return this.props.selectionRange }, // [number, number] 
        set: function (range) { /* dispatch store action to update, which will update props */ }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      focusHandler() {
        if (this.selectionRange[1] !== 0) { this.select() }
      },
      selectionHandler(e) { 
        this.selectionRange = [e.currentTarget.selectionStart, e.currentTarget.selectionEnd]
      },
      blurHandler() {
        this.selectionRange = [0, 0]
      },
      select() {
        this.$refs['someRefName'].setSelectionRange(this.selectionRange[0], this.selectionRange[1])
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```